# Unwanted border around absolute div's in div-container

Tags: html

I've created a large div-container that can contain multiple items (div's),
like that:
[image: container]

But, as you can see, there is an unwanted white gap at the bottom and to the right of each item and I don't know where this is coming from.
The items should be scrollable if they not fit into the Container (horizontally)

HTML:

```
<div class="maincontainer">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.maincontainer {
    width: 90%; 
    min-height: 200px; 
    margin: auto; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;     
    overflow-x: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: #444444;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.box{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    width:180px;  
    background-color:#666666;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:80px;
    width:160px;  
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

I've also made a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xu4RvjicJtTDxkSwRxgc?p=preview)

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: try to change  `display: inline-block;` to `float:left;`

Comment: this partly works, but then the Items are no longer horizontally scrollable and stack vertically after reaching the right of the maincontainer. I should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Setting the maincontainer's font size to 0 does it! Googled removing whitespaces in css and found:

[this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: I will, but I can't until tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

By default, your divs are `block` elements, however, you changed them to `inline` elements. `Inline` elements have a whitespace. That is why there is a gap between your two elements.

You can change the maincontainer `display` to `flex` like so:

```
.maincontainer {
    width: 90%; 
    display:flex;
    min-height: 200px; 
    margin: auto; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;     
    overflow-x: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.container {

    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;  
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: #444444;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.box{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    width:180px;  
    background-color:#666666;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:80px;
    width:160px;  
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

That should be it! :)

Comment: This somehow squeezes the items to a lower width